# Desplegar dos ventanas y destruir solo una en openCV

Tags: python, opencv

Buenos días/tardes/noches:
Estoy usando openCV y en mi codigo uso la camara y despliego tanto la camara(frame), como una imagen con una linea, cuadrado y circulo, lo que quiero lograr es destruir solo la imagen al presionar la q en el teclaod, pero seguir desplegando la webcam, estoy usando la función destroyWindow(), pero no se destruye
Este es mi codigo.`

```
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
while True:
    grabbed, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.line(img,(0,0),(511,511),(255,0,0),5)
    cv2.rectangle(img,(384,0),(510,128),(0,255,0),3)
    cv2.circle(img,(447,63), 63, (0,0,255), -1)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    cv2.putText(img,"OPENCV",(10,500), font, 4,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.imshow("imagen", img)
    cv2.imshow("webcam",frame)
    if(cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q')):
        cv2.destroyWindow("imagen")

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema no es que no se destruya, que lo hace, el problema es que en la siguiente iteración `cv2.imshow` vuelve a crear la ventana.

Creo que una opción simple sería usar un condicional junto a una variable bandera que indique si debe o no mostrarse dicha ventana.

```
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)

show_image = True

while True:
    grabbed, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.line(img,(0,0),(511,511),(255,0,0),5)
    cv2.rectangle(img,(384,0),(510,128),(0,255,0),3)
    cv2.circle(img,(447,63), 63, (0,0,255), -1)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    cv2.putText(img,"OPENCV",(10,500), font, 4,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord('q'):
        if show_image:
            cv2.destroyWindow("imagen")
        show_image = not show_image
    elif key == 27:
        break

    if show_image:
        cv2.imshow("imagen", img)        

    cv2.imshow("webcam",frame)


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Pulsando <kbd>q</kbd> se puede cerrar y volver a mostrar la ventana en cualquier momento. Por otro lado, <kbd>ESC</kbd> termina el ciclo.